# Image in template are not displayd

Tags: django

I can't display image in my template. This is my code:

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'my_static'),
)
```

in my models:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images')
```

in website source(ctrl+U in firefox):

```
<img class="preview_image" src="static/images/test_1.png" ale="photo" />
```

How display image correctly?

Comment: Try to add first slash, i.e. `src="/static/images/test_1.png"`

Comment: Not working. If I try 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/test_1.png -> Page not found (404)

Comment: How do you put image file url in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `MEDIA_URL` like this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then change `upload_to` parameter like this:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Add this to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

Then access the uploaded image in your template like below:

```
<img src="{{ picture.photo.url }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing MEDIA_URL -

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then change the upload_to parameter on your model

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Add an images folder to your MEDIA_ROOT directory (I can't tell where that is as I don't know what your `DIRNAME` variable is)

```
/path/to/your/media_root/images
```

Now you can display a photo in a template using -

```
{% your_object.photo.url %}
```

Don't hard code url's in your template -

```
<img class="preview_image" src="static/images/test_1.png" ale="photo" />
```

should be -

```
<img class="preview_image" src="{% your_object.photo.url %}" ale="photo" />
```

Have a look at the docs on [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) and [serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/).

When you save your model (with a photo), the photo is uploaded to `<MEDIA_ROOT>/<upload_to>`. It's then served up over http from `http://localhost:8000/<MEDIA_URL>/<upload_to>`. However since you're saving your photo in a model, the database keeps a reference to the location of the file allowing you to load the image with `<img src="{% object.photo.url %}">`.